# C#: Select ParentId and Child Text Values

Tags: c#, linq

I have a business object model that looks like so:

```
Parent
   string ParentType
   List<Child> ChildCollectionList

Child
   int ChildId
   string ChildText
```

My objective is a List of Tuples that have this signature

```
Tuple<ParentType,List<string>>  resultingTuple
```

where the List is comprised of the ChildTexts in the ChildCollectionList collection.

Right now, I've got something like this.

```
context.TruckSet.Where(n => n.IsDeleted.Equals(false))
   .Select(p => 
     new Tuple<string,List<string>>      
         (p.TruckType,p.TruckAttributes.Select(n => n.AttrText)
                    .ToList())).ToList();
```

Needless to say, the Linq query doesn't like that little expansion I have of the TruckAttributes collection.

I'm not sure what I am supposed to do.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: why are you selecting a string if you need a `ParentType` ?

Answer (score 0):

Your example of what you already have implemented is a bit confusing, as it doesn't match to the model you describe above. But considering you just want to create that Tuple-List from your model, the following could help:

```
IList<Tuple<string, IList<string>>> result = 
  parents.Select(p => 
    Tuple.Create(p.ParentType, p.ChildCollectionList.Select(c => c.ChildText).ToList()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following linq:

```
List<string> result = (from childItem in yourParentName.ChildCollectionList
             select childItem.childText).ToList();
```

Now, when you have the list of texts you can write the following:

```
Tuple<ParentType,List<string>> resultingTuple = 
            new Tuple<ParentType,List<string>>(yourParentName,result)
```